# Get one single record when existing duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have an ingredients translations table this form (some columns have been removed for simplicity, but still required in the result)

```
| id | name         | ingredient_id | language |
|  1 | Water        |            11 |       en |
|  2 | Bell pepper  |            12 |       en |
|  3 | Sweet pepper |            12 |       en |
```

I'm trying to build a query to retrieve just one single ingredient translation per ingredient like this (expected result)

```
| id | name         | ingredient_id |
|  1 | Water        |            11 |
|  2 | Bell pepper  |            12 |
```

So far now I'm trying to do it with this query

```
select it1.*
from ingredient_translations it1 
  left outer join ingredient_translations it2 
    on  it1.ingredient_id = it2.ingredient_id
    and it1.id < it2.id 
where it1.language = 'es'
```

but it's now giving the expected results :/

```
flag
```

I'm using postgresql, though I was trying to do this using joins so I can device a cross-db (Postgresql - MySQL) solution.

Please, any insight will be apreciated!!! :D

Comment: `mysql` / `sql-server` ?

Comment: i'm using postgresql, though i was trying to do this using joins so i can device a cross-db (postgresql - mysql) solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CustomerCTE (
  SELECT t1.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ingredient_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS RN
  FROM ingredient_translations  t1
  INNER JOIN ingredient_translations   t2 ON t1.ingredient_id  = t2.ingredient_id  
  )

SELECT * FROM CustomerCTE WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` over `partition`.

**Query**

```
select id,name,ingredient_id,language from 
(
    select id,name,ingredient_id,language,
    row_number() over
    (
        partition by ingredient_id
        order by id
    ) rn
    from tbl_Name
)t
where t.rn < 2;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2144a/4)